# How can I create a subdomain in AWS Route53 when the parent domain is also configured in Route53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, amazon-route53

I have one domain name registered in an AWS Hosted zone. It comprises of 5 records viz A, SOA, NS (4 ns addresses), MX and CNAME. But now, I want to create a Subdomain : `static.domain.com`. I have read [Creating a Subdomain That Uses Amazon Route 53 as the DNS Service without Migrating the Parent Domain](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingNewSubdomain.html) article from AWS doc but clearly that is not my case. My domain name is configured in the Route53 itself.

So if I have to create a hosted zone for the `static.domain.com` and update the NS records in the parent's hosted zone `domain.com` then I can just do that but I am confused if that's gonna work or destroy my whole configuration!

So guys, please tell me how to create the subdomain `static.domain.com` when my parent domain `domain.com` is also in the Route53?

**FYI :** I am creating this subdomain to serve static content from an s3 bucket which will be configured as an static website and will be aliased against this subdomain `static.domain.com` so that all static requests are can be fetched as `http://static.domain.com/resources/path/to/dir/image.png` etc.

Thanks very much

Comment: *static.domain.com* is not a subdomain.  *domain.com* is a subdomain of *.com* (really, it is).  for *static.domain.com* to be considered a subdomain, you need to prefix it with a host.  For example *image.static.domain.com* where *image* would be the *host* and then *static.domain.com* could be considered a subdomain.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is create a record set in your Hosted Zone, for your desired sub domain.

1. Go to your Hosted Zone
2. Click the 'Create Record Set' Button
3. In the dialog that appears on the right, enter your desired subdomain in the 'name' field. If you want static.domain.com, just enter 'static' in the name field.
4. Choose the Type of DNS Record you want eg, A, CNAME
5. Enter a custom TTL if desired, enter value(s) for your record and change the routing policy if also desired.

Comment: Are you saying entering a record of any type with a sub domain name will create a sub domain?

Comment: Absolutely. A sub domain can be any record type.

Comment: Okay say my parent doman is `domain.com` then to create a subdomain within the same hosted zone (like u said) I will create `static.domain.com` as a CNAME record. Then how does it work as a subdomain when any request made to this `static.domain.com` will be redirected to `domain.com` ?

Comment: If you create a CNAME record for static.domain.com, static.domain.com will resolve to whatever value(s) you set for the CNAME. A CNAME maps one domain to another, so if you set the value to be domain.com, your sub domain will resolve to domain.com.

Comment: I don't need to map when I want this subdomain to serve itself, right?

Comment: One very important question, Please be sure enough to answer this, Do I need to create another hosted zone to create a subdomain provided that the parent domain is hosted within a Route53 hosted zone?

Comment: What do you mean when you want this subdomain to serve itself? No, as my post above states all you need to do is create a record set. You don't need to create a hosted zone for the subdomain. If you follow the steps in my post and play around with record sets, you will learn by doing.

Comment: this doesn't make sense. Creating a random record (say *A Record* with a name of *test* and a value of *1.1.1.1.*) in the parent domain (*example.com*) that matches a subdomain (*test.example.com*) makes the subdomain work?  No....  by definition that is not a subdomain, that's simply a host record.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Create records in the existing hosted zone for the domain
2. Create an additional (dedicated) hosted zone for the subdomain, and create records in this dedicated hosted zone.

Both are explained below.

#### Option 1 (without a dedicated hosted zone)

In this case all we possibly can do is to change the list of the DNS records. And I believe primary record types to be configured are:

- The A record type. It's like a [domain name to IP address] record.
  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/ResourceRecordTypes.html#AFormat
- **or** the CNAME record type. This one is like a [domain name to another domain name] record
  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/ResourceRecordTypes.html#CNAMEFormat

Note: NS record should not be changed, its value should remain default and is used as a primary link between the name servers and the hosted zone. The hosted zone itself is kinda named AWS container for DNS records (i. e. a thing that can be referenced within AWS ecosystem).

#### Option 2

1. Create a hosted zone that has the same name as the subdomain that you want to route traffic for, such as acme.example.com.
2. Create records in the new hosted zone that define how you want to route traffic for the subdomain (acme.example.com) and its subdomains, such as backend.acme.example.com.

-> You get the name servers that Route 53 assigned to the new hosted zone when you created it.

3. Create a new NS record in the hosted zone for the domain (example.com), and you specify the four name servers that you got after step #2.

Option 2 **pros**: having a dedicated hosted zone provides more flexibility for configuration and managing access to this configuration for other AWS users (IAM permissions). "Flexibility" here can be for example having *not the same* DNS service used for the domain and for the subdomain

Option 2 **cons**: "small" performance impact to this configuration for the first DNS query from each DNS resolver. The resolver must get information from the root-domain's hosted zone first and then get information from the subdomain's hosted zone. But there is a caching mechanism regulated by TTL (Time to live) value.

Reference: 'Routing traffic for subdomains'
Mon Oct 24 19:59:40 PDT 2022
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-routing-traffic-for-subdomains.html

See also an option-2-related article: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/create-subdomain-route-53/

Hope it helps and is somewhat educational.